# ¿Cómo obtener .XML desde solicitud HttpResponseMessage?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Desarrollo una aplicacion  donde envio una Json a una REST Api y como respuesta deberia obtener desde unas de sus cabezeras una URL , Hasta alli todo bien pero ademas de esto el servidor devuelve un archivo .xml el cual debo obtener

¿Como puedo hacerlo?

Mi codigo :

```
 public async Task EnviarDocumentoPost(string accessToken)
        {
            DocumentoElectronicoFactura.DocumentoFactura MetodoCreacion = new DocumentoElectronicoFactura.DocumentoFactura();
            string resultadoCrear = MetodoCreacion.CrearDocumentoFactura(directorio, nombreArchivoXml, SetearModeloFactura());
            string[] partes = resultadoCrear.Split('/');
            string consecutivo= partes[0];
            string clave = partes[1];

            FirmaXadesEpes.Firma MetodoFirmar = new FirmaXadesEpes.Firma();
            string resultadoFirmar = MetodoFirmar.FirmarXadesEpes(directorio + nombreArchivoXml);

            CreadorJson.JsonDoc Creador = new CreadorJson.JsonDoc();
            string jsonDocumento = Creador.CadenaJsonSolicitud("FacturaElectronica", clave ,consecutivo,"02", "3101408861", "02", "3101408861", @"C:\Users\Public\Documents\", "FacturaElectronica");
            byte[] arrayBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonDocumento);

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            HttpResponseMessage response=await client.PostAsync("https://api.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/recepcion-sandbox/v1/recepcion/", new StringContent(jsonDocumento, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                urlValidacion = response.Headers.Location.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Transaccion Fallida : " + response.ToString());
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes emplear el siguiente código para recuperar el contenido de una respuesta

```
var xml = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```